# Error: Cannot find module '../proxy/rules'

Tags: javascript, npm

```
Error: Cannot find module '../proxy/rules'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\James\Desktop\Bootcamp\react portfolio\reactPortfolio\webpack\dev.config.js:6:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I can't get my npm to start. I've tried deleting and reinstalling npm, updating it, restarting the terminal, changing the call, moving the folder, removing and reinstalling node_modules, removing the package.json and package-lock.json and reinstalling them.

Comment: seems like your relative path in the import statement is incorrect. try `cmd + click` (mac) or `ctrl + click`(windows) on the import statement path from your IDE, should take you to the file.

Comment: The proxy file should be found. It's in the right place with the right call. The only link for a file is in the debug report. The call should be the absolute path as it is just going back one directory directly into proxy.